# Unable to connect my android phone (XOLO a500) to adb

Tags: android, usb, android-permissions

Unable to connect phone with adb under Ubuntu (64-bit) , it shows

```
List of devices attached 
????????????    no permissions
```

I am using android device (XOLO A500), i goggled for its vender id so that i can add it in 51-android.rules file but i didn't found vender id.

Is there any way to connect my phone with adb ?

Thanks,

Comment: i am also searching for its vender id.. if u find plz post it.. thnkz

Comment: Try snappea. Use the USB storage mode while connecting it to your machine, turn on the USB debugging mode. Now connect the phone(Xolo Q700) via snappea, it will search and download appropriate drivers automatically...FYI, Xolo uses HTC drivers

Answer (score 1):

> I am using android device (XOLO A500), i goggled for its vender id so that i can add it in 51-android.rules file but i didn't found vender id.

Your observed `adb devices` output is indeed consistent with not having the permissions to the device normally granted by a udev rule.

On a linux system such as yours, you can determine the vendor ID of an attached Android device by issuing the `lsusb` command.

If there is any doubt about which device is the phone, issue it both with the phone connected and unconnected, and the device of interest will be the difference.

Once you have created the rule, you will need to tell udev to reload its rules and then likely replug the device (rebooting is a more drastic but effective alternative).

Answer (score 0):

You can find the **Vender Id** from **Device Manager** -->> Right click on the **Drivers**-->> select the **property**---> select the **details** in that you can get the details of the device with vender id etc..

Comment: Windows device manager is not an answer to the question asked, which specified a ubuntu (linux) system.

Answer (score 0):

Xolo phones (Q700) use YunOS ACB Interface drivers for USB debugging.

You can download from http://binarydb.com/driver/YunOS-ACB-Interface-240854.html

I tried with HTC drivers, it didnt work.

Comment: The question concerns a **linux** system, so windows drivers will not help. Typically there is not really a "driver" used with adb under linux, rather the adb server talks directly to the operating system USB APIs.

Comment: I agree Chris on your observation. Actually the fact is I myself had same query for Windows system, and my search ended up to this post. So when i found the ans to it, thought of putting information here itself, as others may also end up to this post :)